# Kubernetes: using bash variable expansion in container entrypoint

Tags: bash, kubernetes, environment-variables

According to the [documentation][1] Kubernetes variables are expanded using the previous defined environment variables in the container using the syntax $(VAR_NAME). The variable can be used in the container's entrypoint.

For example:

```yaml
env:
- name: MESSAGE
  value: "hello world"
command: ["/bin/echo"]
args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```

Is this possible though to use bash expansion aka `${Var1:-${Var2}}` inside the container's entrypoint for the kubernetes environment variables E.g.

```yaml
env:
- name: Var1
  value: "hello world"
- name: Var2
  value: "no hello"
command: ['bash', '-c', "echo ${Var1:-$Var2}"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible though to use bash expansion aka `${Var1:-${Var2}}` inside the container's entrypoint ?

Yes, by using

```
command: 
- /bin/bash
- "-c"
- "echo ${Var1:-${Var2}}"
```

but not otherwise -- kubernetes is not a wrapper for bash, it use the Linux `exec` system call to launch programs inside the container, and so the only way to get bash behavior is to launch bash

That's also why they chose `$()` syntax for their environment interpolation so it would be different from the `${}` style that a shell would use, although this question comes up so much that one might wish they had not gone with `$` anything to avoid further confusing folks

Comment: Thanks daniel! I updateed the question. Will this work also if the variables are kubernetes variables? As stated in the documentation $() syntax is used to get the value of previous defined environment variables in the container

Comment: It took you longer to type out that comment and the question update than it would have to try it; yes, env vars are made available to the bash entrypoint, and will be evaluated in their normal bash-y way

Comment: Also note that this won't work in an os-less container.